# Slow down potential attackers

Tags: iptables

My server occasionally get massively hit by (probably bots) on a small group of IPs.  Is there a good way (probably in iptables) to slow down or temporarily block/tarpit connections coming from an IP that has connected many times recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, iptables supports this kind of dynamic rate limiting.

See here for details: http://codingfreak.blogspot.com/2010/01/iptables-rate-limit-incoming.html

Comment: Hmm... it seems that I cannot set a --hitcount over 20... that's not very useful in this case.  Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) would be a useful tool for you.

Comment: I'm using denyhosts already for ssh traffic, yes :)

Comment: Denyhosts needs an auth log to read... These are not failures of any kind, just DNS queries.